# Spark Unit Tests Fails With java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError(ScalaTest)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalatest

This is how my spark unit tests are written

```
class SparkReaderTest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll{
  @transient
  var spark:SparkSession = _
  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    spark=
      SparkSession
        .builder()
        .master("local[*]")
        .appName("SparkScalaTest")
        .getOrCreate()
  }
  override  def afterAll(): Unit = {
    spark.stop()
  }
  test("test for utilities for read operations"){
    assert(txtToDFDefault("mockfiles.log",spark).count()>1,"reading raw data")
}
}
```

My pom.xml is like this

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalactic</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalactic_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.133.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>28.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>0.21.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>failureaccess</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>listenablefuture</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.116.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api-scala_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>2.12.1</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
                <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>2.12.1</scalaVersion>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>2.12.1</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
                <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>2.12.1</scalaVersion>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

When I try to run mvn clean install command , it fails with the following error

```
[INFO] --- scalatest-maven-plugin:1.0:test (test) @ decisionengine-data-ingestion-maven ---
Discovery starting.
Discovery completed in 267 milliseconds.
Run starting. Expected test count is: 10
SparkWriterTest:
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
21/10/06 00:49:52 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.8
21/10/06 00:49:52 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
*** RUN ABORTED ***
  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:116)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:93)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:73)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:293)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:283)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:260)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:789)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:774)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:647)
  ...
  Cause: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
  at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3751)
  at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:50)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:116)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:93)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:73)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:293)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:283)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:260)
  ...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```